# conversion of JS button to Lightning salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a JS button, which is calling a web service class method and doing some process. I am trying to convert that to call a VF page and make it lightning compatible. But I am stuck on an error while calling the web service method in the pageref. Pls suggest

```
global class AddUserToNewTeam{
    public Opportunity objOpp;
  
    global AddUserToTeam(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) {
        objOpp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
    }
    
    public pagereference addTeam(){

     addTeamMember(objOpp.Id); ****ERROR HERE: Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addTeamMember(Id) from the type  AddUserToNewTeam****

      return new pagereference(url.getsalesforcebaseurl().toexternalform()+'/'+objOpp.Id);
    }
  
 webservice static boolean addTeamMember(List<Id> opptyIds)
    {
    //all logic
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a single Id `objOpp.Id`, but your method expects a `List<Id>`

`addTeamMember(List<Id> opptyIds)`

So, you can create a list and pass that to the method

```
public pagereference addTeam(){
  List<Id> opportunityIds = new List<Id>();
  opportunityIds.add(objOpp.Id);
  addTeamMember(opportunityIds);
}
```

Or, depending on whether this is the only use case for this method - update the method to accept a single Id and keep the other parts of your code

`addTeamMember(Id opptyId)`